# Select random number and add to ArrayList

Tags: java

So for example I have a small piece of code that looks like this...

```
public int random1;
public int random2;
List<Integer> listOfNums =Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ArrayList<Integer> numberSelected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Public ArrayList<Integer> selectNums{
    random1 = ...
    random2 = ...
}
```

What would be the quickest and cleanest way of having random1 and random2 select a random number from listOfNums and then putting that number in the numberSelected ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
numberSelected.add(listOfNums.get(random1));
numberSelected.add(listOfNums.get(random2));
```

Ensure that `random1` and `random2` are within the bounds of `listOfNums`.

Comment: Wouldn't .get be trying to get whatever is that the index position of what is inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Um. We might be understanding the same thing in different ways. random1 and random2 represent the numbers from listOfNums that will be picked randomly. Random1 and random2 in this case would either be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6. Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: Because they are random. You could either get from example 2 and 5 or 1 and 4. It could be different every time I call the selectNums method

Comment: @M.Pollino so if we have a list of `[12,4,9,2,0,4]`  then what would be the possible random numbers?  is it `0,1,2,3,4,5` ? if that is the case then my solution is the one you want and you should give it a try ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //Generate a random number in [0,5]
numberSelected.add(listOfNums[random1]); //Add listOfNums[random1] to numberSelected
listOfNums.splice(random1, 1); //Remove listOfNums[random1] from listOfNums
var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); //Generate another random number in [0,4]
numberSelected.add(listOfNums[random2]); //Add listOfNums[random2] to numberSelected
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did? Code only answers are often not that helpful, thanks.